# Параметры JSON при отправке запроса HTTP

Tags: json, javascript, java

по стандарту *JSON* выглядят так:

```
{a: 123, b: ["123","123"]}
```

при отправке(*XMLHTTPRequest.send()* из Javascript) объект упаковывается в строку, но при этом имена параметров заключаются в двойные кавычки:

```
'{"a": 123, "b": ["123","123"]}'
```

Зачем упаковывать имена параметров в кавычки?Ведь принимающая сторона сможет и так отпарсить объект и сделать mapping в JAVA объект, например.

PS можно ли в Java Servlets обрабатывать запросы типа *Content-type: application/json*, тоесть получать и обрабатывать JSON-объект-строку без параметра?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@voipp](/users/12796/voipp)](/users/12796/voipp), я вас огорчу, но [по стандарту](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) JSON выражение выглядит именно так:

```
{"a": 123, "b": ["123","123"]}
```

Выражение в вашем первом примере - это просто валидный js объект, но не JSON.

> Зачем упаковывать имена параметров в кавычки?

Вероятно, для упрощения грамматики. Строки в кавычках так и так должны в нее входить, вот их и использовали повторно.

> можно ли в Java Servlets обрабатывать запросы типа Content-type: application/json, то есть получать и обрабатывать JSON-объект-строку без параметра

**UPD**. Можно, вот пример:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (req.getContentType().equals("application/json")){
            InputStream is = req.getInputStream();

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Map<String, Object> foo = mapper.readValue(is, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() { });

            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            resp.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
            writer.append("<html><body>\n");
            writer.append("<div>a: " + foo.get("a") + "</div>\n");
            writer.append("<div>b: ");
            for(String s : (ArrayList<String>)foo.get("b")) {
                writer.append(s);
                writer.append("; ");
            }
            writer.append("</div>\n");
            writer.append("</body></html>");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } else {
            resp.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE_415);
        }
    }
}
```

Для POST-запроса с содержимым `{"a": 123, "b": ["Hello","World"]}` этот сервлет вернет такой HTML:

```
<html><body>
<div>a: 123</div>
<div>b: Hello; World; </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: а как можно? Я нигде  в гугле не найду(

Comment: Опишите чуть подробнее, что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @Nofate ♦ хочу отправлять запрос так:

     XMLHttpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(someJavaScriptObject));


а в сервлете обрабатывать. Здесь важно, что *content* http-запроса не содержит строк вида *variable=blah-blah&variable2=blah-blah2*, только чистый *JSON* объект. Проблема в том, что для получения контента запроса , в сервлете есть только функции *getParameter*

Comment: > Проблема в том, что для получения контента запроса , в сервлете есть только функции `getParameter`.

@voipp, [getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)), как и следует из названия, служит для обращения к параметрам запроса. Для чтения тела запроса используется метод [getInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream()).

Я вам сообразил небольшой пример по получению JSON-строки из POST-запроса и разбору ее при помощи `ObjectMapper` из библиотеки Jackson.